# Foreign keys and entity relationships

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am writing a simple program to track Golf records and I am seeing some strange results with entity relationships.
My table `Hole` has a foreign key relationship on it's `CourseId` column and the `Course` tables `Id` column.

When I run the following

```
using (var context = new DataAccess.Entities())
            {
                var courseId = 0;
                var holesInCourse = context.Holes.Where(x => x.CourseId == courseId);
                var holeList = holesInCourse.ToList();
            }
```

[image]

You can see that it returned the list of 9 holes for the given course of 0

However when I change the query to the following:

```
using (var context = new DataAccess.Entities())
            {
                var courseId = 0;
                var holesInCourse = context.Courses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == courseId);
                var holeList = holesInCourse.Holes.ToList();
            }
```

[image]

I am a bit lost why the second one only returns 4 rows when it clearly has relationship to 9. Is it the way that I am building my query?

Comment: are you using lazy loading? can you try this: ` context.Courses.Includ("Holes")` to see what happens

Comment: What do the queries of both `ToList` calls look like?

Comment: Enabling lazy loading did not resolve the issue, I think I am going to scrap using FK constraints here as it is just overly complex for what I am doing.

Comment: could you provide the entries in your database tables?

Comment: I opted to remove the FK constraints and just build a wrapper for the access object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code,
`var holesInCourse = context.Courses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == courseId);`
you are assigning `courseId=0;`
thats why you are not getting proper answer.here linq will try to take list with `courseId=0` value from database.